# Screen tearing issue after using nvidia proprietary driver in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I've installed recommended nvidia proprietary driver(nvidia-driver-435). After the installation and restarting, screen tearing start to happen. I searched in the internet, everyone trying to different solution. I've tried some of them, but didn't work.
Here's the CPU and Graphics info:

```
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-4510U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Haswell rev: 1 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 20750 
  Speed: 905 MHz min/max: 800/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1618 2: 1582 
  3: 1619 4: 1765 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics 
  vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 840M] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
  driver: nvidia v: 435.21 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 840M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21 
  direct render: Yes
```

Comment: I've already asked in 3 forums including linux mint forums

Comment: What happens if you alter the screen refresh rate? Does tearing get better, worse, or no change?